# Update a lookup field to null

Tags: apex, field-update

I need to update a lot of record to change their lookup field to null, I tried following code:

```
public class UpdateContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Profil__c from Contact__c]);

}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact__c> scope){  
    for(Contact__c contactC:scope){
         contactC.Profil__c = null;
         update ContactC;}}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

} }
```

But this code isn't working, I got the following error: First error: Invalid id:

So Apex is not considering null as an id, but I want to turn that Profil field to empty could you help me to do it ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should Declare `Id` variable and initialized with as `null` in top then assign that in for loop like below and do the update in out side the loop.

```
public class UpdateContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
  Id profilid = null;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Profil__c from Contact__c];

    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact__c> scope){  
        for(Contact__c contactC:scope)
        {
            contactC.Profil__c = profilid;
        }

        Update scope;

    }  

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your code somewhat to get it to even compile. Beyond that, you should move your `update` out of the loop.

```
public class UpdateContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id, Profil__c from Contact__c];
        // above line was missing terminating semicolon
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact__c> scope){  
        for(Contact__c contactC:scope)
        {
            contactC.Profil__c = null;
        }
        // moved this closing bracket before the DML
        // so you can update entire collection at once
        update scope;
    }
    // this closing bracket was missing
    // so instead you declared the finish method here
    // which would cause a compile fail

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { }
    // you had two closing brackets here
}
```

Comment: I did it and it doesn't work, the problem is contactC.Profil__c = null;
Profil__c is a lookup field and it must refer to an id, so I got the error invalid ID